# Combine multiple observables from rxjs into a single buffer

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have 2 websocket connections (using `LiveQuery` from `Parse` if that makes a difference).

For each websocket I have 3 events that I want to capture, `"create"`, `"update"`, and `"delete"`.

A bunch of updates are likely to come at once, so for a single event I use a buffer to capture a sequence of updates that come through at once:

```
const base = fromEvent(listener, type);
const triggerBuffer = base.pipe(debounceTime(500));
const buffered = base.pipe(buffer(triggerBuffer));
```

That works fine. When a bunch of updates come from the server they get buffered and are all emitted at once.

What I want is to combine all of the events from both websockets into a single update. I've tried to achieve this with the `zip` operator like so:

```
const setupServerObservable = (listener, listenerName) => type => {
  const base = fromEvent(listener, type);
  return base.pipe(map(x => ({ [listenerName]: { [type]: x } })));
};

const setupServerObservables = subscriptions => {
  const joins = setupServerObservable(subscriptions.joins, "joins");
  const containers = setupServerObservable(
    subscriptions.containers,
    "containers"
  );

  const eventTypes = ["update", "create", "delete"];

  const allJoins = eventTypes.map(joins);
  const allContainers = eventTypes.map(containers);
  const all = allJoins.concat(allContainers);
  const zippedObservables = zip(all);
  console.log(zippedObservables);
  const triggerBuffer = zippedObservables.pipe(debounceTime(500));
  const buffered = zippedObservables.pipe(buffer(triggerBuffer));
  return buffered;
};
```

But when I try to subscribe to this newly created `Observable` it doesn't emit any updates from the server. That `console.log(zippedObservables)` produces the following output:

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: ZipOperator}
operator: ZipOperator
    resultSelector: Array(6)
     0: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
     1: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
     2: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
     3: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
     4: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
     5: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
source: Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
_isScalar: false
__proto__: Object
```

I think I'm probably misunderstanding what the `zip` operator does but I wasn't able to make it work with `merge` or `concat` either.

Comment: This article should help you understand how `zip` works. https://scotch.io/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom

Comment: @pindev that was a really useful tutorial. It seems though that none of those operators are what I'm looking for. Is there another operator that will simply emit an event from any of the other observables in whatever order they arrive?

Comment: I think `combineLatest` is for it. https://scotch.io/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom#toc-combinelatest-the-go-dutch-operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I looked at the tutorial posted in the comments I realised that `zip` was not what I wanted.

I tried the same thing with `merge` but it didn't work. It seems that `merge` does not accept an array, it has to accept each `Observable` to merge as a separate parameter like so:

```
const merged = merge(all[0], all[1], all[2], all[3], all[4], all[5]);
```

So the final code is:

```
const setupServerObservable = (listener, listenerName) => type => {
  const base = fromEvent(listener, type);
  return base.pipe(map(x => ({ [listenerName]: { [type]: x } })));
};

const setupServerObservables = subscriptions => {
  const joins = setupServerObservable(subscriptions.joins, "joins");
  const containers = setupServerObservable(
    subscriptions.containers,
    "containers"
  );

  const eventTypes = ["update", "create", "delete"];

  const allJoins = eventTypes.map(joins);
  const allContainers = eventTypes.map(containers);
  const all = allJoins.concat(allContainers);
  const merged = merge(all[0], all[1], all[2], all[3], all[4], all[5]);
  const triggerBuffer = merged.pipe(debounceTime(500));
  const buffered = merged.pipe(buffer(triggerBuffer));
  return buffered;
};
```

It would be nice if there was a way to do this with an array but it seems not.